# jquery offset method doesn't always work / exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good morning and happy new year everyone!

I've run into a snag on something and need to figure out a solution or an alternative, and I don't know how to approach this. I actually hope it's something easy; meaning one of you all have dealt with this already.

The problem is that I'm doing rollovers that contain information. They're divs that get moved to the absolute location. Now I've tried this with jquery 1.6 - 1.9.1. Of course this has to work in multiple browsers.

What needs to happen is on rollover show a div, and when you rollout of that div, make it hide.

```
...
// .columnItem is class level and works
$(".columnItem").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css("display", "none");
});
...

$(".column").mouseenter(function() {
    var currentItem = $(this)[0]; // this is where the problem is

    // hide all .columnItems
    $(".columnItem").css("display", "none");

    // i get this error: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'offset' (viewing in chrome console)
    var offsetTop = currentItem.offset().top;

    var columnInfoPanel = $("#column" + currentItem.innerText);
});
```

So the immediate thought of some would be don't use `$(this)[0]`. Instead, I should use `$(this)`, and you are correct! Where the other problem comes into play is by removing the array index, `currentItem.innerText` is now `undefined`.

The only thing I can think of is I'll have to mix both, but it seems like there should be a way to use the selector and get both options.

What have you all done?

Thanks,
Kelly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
var currentItem = $(this)[0];
```

With:

```
var currentItem = $(this).eq(0);
```

This creates a new jQuery object containing only the first element, so `offset` will work.

Then you can use either `currentItem[0].innerText` or `currentItem.text()`, whichever you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about that, I really appreciate it. I had no idea about the `eq()` method. Also I changed to call `text()` to keep things common.

Answer (score 0):

Skip the [0] at the beginning as you are saying.
But then change the last line to:

```
 var columnInfoPanel = $("#column" + currentItem[0].innerText);
```

De-referencing the jQuery selector gives you the DOM-object.
If you want to stick to pure jQuery, the .text() / .html() methods will give you the same functionality.